# Congomongo "in" query

Tags: mongodb, clojure, congomongo

How can I use the MongoDB [`$in` query operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/#op._S_in) in a Congomongo query? This was my unsuccessful guess—I couldn't find docs on the query syntax anywhere.

```
(fetch :solutions
       :where {:user {:in [1 2 3]}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operators in Congomongo queries need the `$` prefix:

```
(fetch :solutions
       :where {:user {:$in [1 2 3]}})
```

This also applies to [other operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/) like `$gt`, `$ne`, etc.